# SCons: save/redirect gcc textual output (warnings)

Tags: gcc, scons, io-redirection

I'm using [SCons](http://www.scons.org) to build a project at work, and I'm trying to parse through the textual output from GCC to make a summary report of all the compiler warnings for each target because our build scripts are quite long, and there is a lot of text output to the console.

I've searched Google and this site for quite a while, and I can't find a method built-in to SCons to accomplish this. I've tried redirecting the entire stdout and stderr stream to a file per [this example](http://scons.org/wiki/BuildLog), but only the output from SCons itself is captured and not that of any tools it calls.

My next thought was to find where SCons compiles the arguments to send to GCC and add redirection to the end of the arguments string. After reading the documentation, it seems that the construction variables `CCCOM` and `CXXCOM` contain the command line used to compile. However, when I added the lines below to my SConstruct, nothing changed in the command lines SCons is executing.

```
baseEnv['CCCOM'] += " 2> gcc-c-output.txt"
baseEnv['CXXCOM'] += " 2> gcc-cxx-output.txt"
```

One thing that did work was redirecting the stderr stream on the entire SCons command:

```
scons 2> stderr.txt
```

I would like to avoid this, however, and contain everything within SCons if possible. The output also doesn't necessarily have to go to a file. It can be saved anywhere as long as I can access it to parse and save to a file at the end of the build.

I've searched for so long and come up with nothing, so I don't know what else to try. I have to believe that I'm not the first one who has wanted to do something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here as I figured out what I was doing wrong. The `CCCOM` and `CXXCOM` variables were the correct ones to be modified, but the problem was I was creating shared-library objects, so these variables were not being used. The ones I should have been modifying are `SHCCCOM` and `SHCXXCOM`.

The following code got the job done for redirecting the GCC warning output (warnings and errors are written to stderr only):

```
baseEnv['SHCCCOM'] += " 2> gcc-c-output.txt"
baseEnv['SHCXXCOM'] += " 2> gcc-cxx-output.txt"
```

Hopefully this answer will help others as I could not find much information on this topic when searching.

Answer (score 3):

For full control, you can override the `env['SPAWN']` construction variable. You will then supply a Python method which will be responsible for executing the command line given to it by argument. Typically, you would take this argument and spawn a subprocess (using some form of `subprocess.Popen`). This would make a pass-through replacement for the default `env['SPAWN']`.

But now, you have full control over the `subprocess.Popen` invocation. You are free to redirect `STDOUT`, `STDERR` or both to any buffer/file. You can also do post processing on that output before printing it to the console and/or saving it to a file. I've used this to color warnings in yellow and errors in red, for example.

For sample code on how to override `env['SPAWN']`, check out [this page](http://scons.org/wiki/BuildLog) on the SCons Wiki.

Comment: using the SPAWN method breaks on Windows when the command line gets too long and scons uses a tempfile to perform the link step. :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `CCCOM` and `CXXCOM` construction variables, have you tried with the `CC` and `CXX` variables? [Here's](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/a4916.html) a complete list of the SCons construction variables, just in case.

You may even consider setting `CC` and `CXX` to scripts on your system that does the redirect internally.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the `CCCOM` and `CXXCOM` variables are the commands used to actually compile source files, with all the CFlags, etc. Im surprised you were able to set them, as I thought they were read-only variables.

Comment: I know those variables are the commands actually used to compile which is why I thought they would be good candidates to modify, but SCons appears to be ignoring my modifications. I even tried setting their values to an empty string, and it still compiled fine. I feel like something is not right because I've seen it mentioned to modify those variables while searching for a solution. I didn't think about wrapping the GCC executables, though. I will explore that option while I wait for a potentially more SConsy answer.

Comment: @EarlCrapstone, Im pretty sure the value of those 2 variables will change (will be overwritten) for each cc file compiled, so Im not surprised your mods didnt do anything. Try using the CC and CXX instead and those will indeed make a difference. I have modified them to specify a different compiler and that does work.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong, but since I'm new it won't let me answer my own question for another four hours. @Brady Those variables are actually not changed during the build. My problem was I was building shared-library objects, so it was using `SHCCCOM` and `SHCXXCOM` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use as following;

`baseEnv['CCCOM'][0] += " 2> gcc-c-output.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
baseEnv['SHCCCOM'] += " 2> ${SOURCE}gcc-c-output.txt"
baseEnv['SHCXXCOM'] += " 2> ${SOURCE}gcc-cxx-output.txt"
```

This should give you a separate file for each source file..